What is the limit of the alternating series $F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n z^{T_n}$ as $z\to1$ for a sequence $T_n\sim cn$?
Let $(T_n)_{n>0}$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers and $c>0$ a positive number such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_n}{n}=c$. Write $F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n z^{T_n}$ for a real number $z\in(-1,1)$. What is the limit of $F(z)$ as $z\to1$?
For example, if $T_n=cn+d$ for some integer $d$, then it is easy to see that $F(z)\to-\frac{1}{2}$ as $z\to1$.
Is this true ($F(z)\to-\frac{1}{2}$ as $z\to1$) for any sequence $(T_n)_n$ satisfying the condition stated in the first paragraph? Do you know any counterexamples (if this is not true)? Any help or references would be appreciated!

The answer is no. For example,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n z^{4n+(-1)^n} = - \sum_{m=1}^\infty z^{4(2m-1)-1} + \sum_{m=1}^\infty z^{4(2m)+1} = -\frac{z^3}{1-z^8} + \frac{z^9}{1-z^8} = -\frac{z^3+z^5+z^7}{1+z^2+z^4+z^6}
$$
for $|z|<1$, and so
$$
\lim_{z\to1-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n z^{4n+(-1)^n} = -\frac34.
$$
